# What is the origin of shorthand for "with" -> "w/"?

Tags: style

In many places, I've seen "w/" written where "with" should be. At least, I think that one replaces the other :) I couldn't find anywhere what is the origin of "w/". Is this something in regular usage in the English language?

Comment: This isn't really a question about writing. It would be a better fit for the English channel.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: The answer is provided English stack exchange site at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601665/what-is-the-origin-of-shorthand-for-with-w.

Comment: **wait, and here I thought it was "w."** ?  like,   "He was w. His brother"  -  to be honest, I (rarely) see "He was w/ his brother". Anyway. Good day.